# Windows Batch File Redirect Output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to output some parameter data from a batch file. I can redirect output, no problem. My issue is that I need to ouput something like

`set value1=0`
`set value2=1`
`echo value1 = %value1%>>temp.txt`
`echo value2 = %value2%>>temp.txt`

without a space after the parameter value

But this will not redirect properly due to CMD assuming that %value#% is the redirection value.

So if I do something like

`echo value1 = %value1% >>temp.txt`
`echo value2 = %value2% >>temp.txt`

It works, but I get a space after the parameter value and the next app that reads this file is not under my control and errors out with spaces after the values.

I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>temp.txt echo value1 = %value1%
>>temp.txt echo value2 = %value2%
```

(It is of course important to use quotes on the path if it contains spaces, `>>"c:\some folder\file.txt" echo value1 = %value1%`)

Comment: I figured it out.  

I just needed to quote the variable

'echo value2 = ^%value2%>>temp.txt'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I just needed to quote the variable

`echo value2 = ^%value2%>>temp.txt`

Sorry about that, it kept "escaping" me (bad pun intended).

Comment: Just as a heads up, you need to be careful when putting > after a varible without a space, if the expanded variable ends in space+2  (set "foo=1 2" + echo %foo%>test2.txt) you end up redirecting error out and the result is a empty file!

Comment: Just use my answer, (echo value1 = %value1%)>>temp.txt should also work